# Why does linecache check for the length of the tuple elements in the cache?

Tags: python, caching, linecache

In https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/linecache.py there are 3 instances of this

In `getines`

```
def getlines(filename, module_globals=None):
    if filename in cache:
        entry = cache[filename]
        if len(entry) != 1:
            return cache[filename][2]
```

In `updatecache`

```
def updatecache(filename, module_globals=None):
    if filename in cache:
        if len(cache[filename]) != 1:
            del cache[filename]
```

In `lazycache`

```
def lazycache(filename, module_globals):
    if filename in cache:
        if len(cache[filename]) == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I am writing my own version of linecache and to write the tests for it I need to understand the scenario in which the tuple can be of length 1

There was one scenario in which the statement in `getlines` got executed. It was when the file was accessed for the first time and stored in the cache and then removed before accessing it the second time. But I still cannot figure out why is it there in the other two functions.

It would be very helpful if someone could help me understand the purpose of using this length check.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the places the code stores values in the cache. It can store two different kinds of values under `cache[filename]`:

- A 4-tuple of size, mod time, list of lines, and name ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/linecache.py#L143) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/linecache.py#L111)).
- A 1-tuple of a function that returns a list of lines on demands ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/linecache.py#L175)).

The 1-tuple is used for setting up for lazy loading of modules. Normal files, to lazy-load them, you just `open` and `read`. But module source may be available from the module's loader (found via the import system), but not available just by opening and reading a file—e.g., `zipimport` modules. So `lazycache` has to stash the loader's `get_source` method, so if it later needs the lines, it can get them.

And this means that, whenever it *uses* those cache values, it has to check which kind it's stored and do different things. If it needs the lines now, and it has a lazy 1-tuple, it has to go load the lines (via `updatecache`; if it's checking for cache eviction and it finds a lazy tuple that was never evaluated, it drops it; etc.

Also notice that in `updatecache`, if it's loaded the file from a lazy 1-tuple, it doesn't have a mod time, which means that in `checkcache`, it can't check whether the file is stale. But that's fine for module source—even if you change the file, the old version is still the one that's `import`ed and being used.

---

If you were designing this from scratch, rather than hacking on something that's been in the stdlib since the early 1.x dark ages, you'd probably design this very differently. For example, you might use a class, or possibly two classes implementing the same interface.

Also, notice that a huge chunk of the code in `linecache` is there to deal with special cases related to loading module source that, unless you're trying to build something that reflects on Python code (like `traceback` does), you don't need any of. (And even if you *are* doing that, you'd probably want to use the `inspect` module rather than talking directly to the import system.)

So, `linecache` may not be the best sample code to base your own line cache on.

Comment: Thanks so much @abarnert that was very informative.

I am actually making a generic that stores the file contents in binary rather than a list so now I know that I can drop lazycache from my code.

I am hacking onto linecache because of two reasons:
    (1) It was the fastest caching module I could find 
    (2) Also because I am working under a project deadline and the binary hack on linecache works pretty well and solves the problems.

Thank you for the answer.